# Valgrind: Where is the memory leak occurring?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50, spell-checking

I've been trying to write a spell checker program that takes a dictionary and a text file to find the misspelled words as fast as possible. The first version seems to work (albeit slow) except Valgrind gives me over 1000000 errors! I have no idea of what went wrong, except that something went horribly so. I'd like to know why this happens.

Speller (by CS50):

```
// Implements a spell-checker by CS50

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }
    

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

Dictionary uploading and other operations (by me):

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned long long int N = 50;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char temp_w[LENGTH];
    unsigned int key = hash(word);
    for(node *temp = table[key]; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            temp_w[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->word, temp_w) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)         //Hashed using djb2
{

    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c = *word;
    c = tolower(c);
    while (*word != 0)
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        c = *word++;
        c = tolower(c);

    }

    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char str[LENGTH];
    char counter[1] = "0";
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        //printf("Error: \n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", str) == 1)
    {
        unsigned int key = hash(str);
        //int key = rand();
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(table[key] == NULL)
        {
            table[key] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            table[key]->next = NULL;
            strcpy(table[key]->word, str);
            
        }
        else //if(table[key]->next != NULL)
        {
            temp->next = table[key];
            strcpy(temp->word, str);
            table[key] = temp;
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    long long int words = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        /*if(strcmp(table[i]->word, "0") != 0 && table[i]->next == NULL)
        {
            words++;
            continue;
        }
        else*/
        if(table[i] != NULL)
        {
            for(node *temp = table[i]; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
            {
                words++;
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *temp1 = NULL;
    node *temp2 = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        temp1 = table[i];
        while(temp1 != NULL)
        {
            if(temp1->next != NULL)
            {
                temp2 = temp1 -> next;
                free(temp1);
                temp1 = temp2;
            }
            else free(temp1);
        }
        free(temp2);
        free(table[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Valgrind error message:

```
 ~/pset5/speller/ $ valgrind ./speller texts/constitution.txt
    ==472== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==472== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==472== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==472== Command: ./speller texts/constitution.txt
    ==472== 
    
MISSPELLED WORDS

==472== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==472==    at 0x49D9143: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==472==    by 0x4019E5: check (dictionary.c:35)
==472==    by 0x4015FB: main (speller.c:114)
==472==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==472==    at 0x4011F4: main (speller.c:21)
==472== 
==472== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==472==    at 0x49D9157: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==472==    by 0x49D9157: tolower (ctype.c:44)
==472==    by 0x4019E5: check (dictionary.c:35)
==472==    by 0x4015FB: main (speller.c:114)
==472==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==472==    at 0x4011F4: main (speller.c:21)
==472== 
USConstitution
http
usconstitution
const
html
==472== Invalid read of size 8
==472==    at 0x401D4C: unload (dictionary.c:139)
==472==    by 0x401758: main (speller.c:154)
==472==  Address 0x4b9cd50 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
==472==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==472==    by 0x401D87: unload (dictionary.c:145)
==472==    by 0x401758: main (speller.c:154)
==472==  Block was alloc'd at
==472==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==472==    by 0x401BCE: load (dictionary.c:90)
==472==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==472== 
==472== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==472==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==472==    by 0x401D87: unload (dictionary.c:145)
==472==    by 0x401758: main (speller.c:154)
==472==  Address 0x4b9cd20 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
==472==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==472==    by 0x401D87: unload (dictionary.c:145)
==472==    by 0x401758: main (speller.c:154)
==472==  Block was alloc'd at
==472==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==472==    by 0x401BCE: load (dictionary.c:90)
==472==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==472== 
==472== 
==472== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==472== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==472== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==472== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==472== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==472==
```

I'd like to know why this happens and how to fix it.

Edit:
Added `dictionary.h`:

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the first error Valgrind reports and work out why it is complaining, and fix it.  That should reduce the error count (though as Valgrind stopped at ten million errors, it might not be obvious).  Then work through the next first problem it reports.  Memory leakage isn't a problem until the rest of the errors — illegal accesses, access to previously freed memory, etc — are fixed.

Comment: With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Note that since you've not posted `dictionary.h`, you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  We can't compile your code, therefore, and can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: `strlen(word)` is probably less than `LENGTH` in your `check()` function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've included `dictionary.h` now.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I found so far is that you free `temp2` in `unload()` when you clearly already freed it by calling free on `temp1`.